# Run ansible task only once per each unique fact value

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have a dynamic inventory that assigns a "fact" to each host, called a 'cluster_number'.

The cluster numbers are not known in advance, but there is one or more hosts that are assigned the same number.  The inventory has hundreds of hosts and 2-3 dozen unique cluster numbers.

I want to run a task for all hosts in the inventory, however I want to execute it only once per each group of hosts sharing the same 'cluster_number' value. It does not matter which specific host is selected for each group.

I feel like there should be a relatively straight forward way to do this with ansible, but can't figure out how. I've looked at group_by, when, loop, delegate_to etc. But no success yet.

Comment: I appreciate that you have looked at `group_by`, `when`, etc, but how about you share those attempts so we can debug code rather than _speculating_ what you are trying to do. Be sure to include the actual error message you get, or the bad outcome from that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind play logs cluttering, here's a way:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - group_by:
        key: "single_{{ cluster_number }}"
      when: groups['single_'+cluster_number] | default([]) | count == 0

- hosts: single_*
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

`serial: 1` is crucial in the first play to reevaluate `when` statement on for every host.

After first play you'll have N groups for each cluster with only single host in them.

Comment: This playbook certainly works, however it does produce a lot of PLAY output and the serial execution of the group_by  is a bit slow for a large number of hosts. Combining your and Vladimir's ideas I decided to add an additional hostvar in the dynamic inventory to specify whether the host is a "cluster_controller" or not. I made sure that only one host per cluster number has cluster_controller=true.  For a small inventory your solution works fine.  Благодарю за помощь, Константин.

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to

- [group_by](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/group_by_module.html) the cluster_number
- [run_once](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) a loop over cluster numbers
- and pick the first host from each group.

For example given the *hosts*

```
[test]
test01 cluster_number='1'
test02 cluster_number='1'
test03 cluster_number='1'
test04 cluster_number='1'
test05 cluster_number='1'
test06 cluster_number='2'
test07 cluster_number='2'
test08 cluster_number='2'
test09 cluster_number='3'
test10 cluster_number='3'
[test:vars]
cluster_numbers=['1','2','3']
```

the following playbook

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - group_by: key=cluster_{{ cluster_number }}
    - debug: var=groups['cluster_{{ item }}'][0]
      loop:  "{{ cluster_numbers }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```
> ansible-playbook test.yml | grep groups
"groups['cluster_1'][0]": "test01", 
"groups['cluster_2'][0]": "test06", 
"groups['cluster_3'][0]": "test09",
```

To execute tasks at the targets [include_tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_tasks_module.html) (instead of debug in the loop above) and [delegate_to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) the target

```
- set_fact:
    my_group: "cluster_{{ item }}"
- command: hostname
  delegate_to: "{{ groups[my_group][0] }}"
```

Note: Collect the list *cluster_numbers* from the inventory

```
cluster_numbers: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.cluster_number')|unique }}"
```

Comment: your solution requires updating the inventory with a list of cluster_numbers.  i  took this idea it a bit further and added a variable that specifies if the host is a 'master' for its cluster number. that allows limiting scope of task with a short 'when:' statement.  tnx

Comment: It doesn't. I put *cluster_numbers* to inventory for simplicity. Getting the list is trivial.

Comment: I see your update w/ using json_query. as someone new to ansible I would not have come up with that line easily :).  i used a similar logic inside the dynamic inventory to pick out a cluster_controller. with that var the playbooks look a lot cleaner. Ansible probably needs a built in abstraction for this kind of task, e.g. run_once: <per unique fact>.

Comment: What  might be a use-case for "built in abstraction for ... run_once: <per unique fact>"? IMHO, it won't help to solve your problem. The suggested playbooks are rather efficient. 1) *group_by* over all hosts and 2) walk over the cluster-masters  only.

Comment: There are a few cases when a task needs to run once for a group of hosts sharing the same characteristic. Clusters, load balancers, distributed database nodes usually are controlled from a single member node.  Another case: query a vulnerability database once for each of the OS release levels that exist in the environment.

Comment: Well, the first case is covered by [run_once](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once). Another case is more complex.  There are [Best Practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#best-practices) and [Rolling Updates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation-rolling-updates-and-local-actions) in particular. [ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html) might help with audit too.